# can you use a function to set a field when creating a model (django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have created a model called 'Video' and in the Video class there is a field called videoID. I want videoID to be a randomly generated string but in my solution, there has been some errors.
Here is my solution:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from other.video import generateVideoID

class Video(models.Model):
    videoID = models.TextField(default=generateVideoID(),editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

As you can see in the videoID field I have set the default value to a function that returns a random string. This doesn't work because every time I create an object the videoID has the same string. This is the 'generateVideoID' function:

```
def generateVideoID():
    import random,string

    chars = string.ascii_letters+string.digits+"_-~"

    videoID = ""
    for i in range(12):
        videoID += random.choice(chars)
    return videoID
```

I have tried to use the '**init**' method to set the videoID but that doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using something that is readily available already, like a UUID?

Comment: @dfundako i didn't know it existed so i just made that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, but you should not *call* it, and furthermore it should be defined before you refer to it, so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from other.video import generateVideoID

class Video(models.Model):
    videoID = models.TextField(default=generateVideoID, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

so *without* parenthesis. If you add parenthesis, the function will be called, and the result will be used as default for *all* objects.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use the [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield):

```
from uuid import uuid4

class Video(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Comment: this works but i need to use the videoID in the URL

Comment: You should be able to use this the same way you were previously. You may need to cast the value to a `str` for some things.